# Ubuntu won't boot after crash - initrams kernel panic

Tags: boot, 20.04, initramfs, busybox

after I couldn't do anything anymore while using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS I had to force power-off and now it won't boot anymore. I ran a hardware check and everything appears to be okay (obviously I was particularly concerned about the hard drive).

What happens is that I end up in the BusyBox shell when I try to boot Ubuntu. After typing "exit" to get more information (as suggested in many other threads) I get this:
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/reOMx.jpg)

That happens regardless if I try kernel 5.4.0-53 or 5.4.0-52. I don't have any other options during startup.

Switching to recovery mode (again it doesn't matter which kernel) I got some more output and then repeatedly this: [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7AZCJ.jpg)

I tried to get access to my data using Ubuntu Live CD, but there is no /dev/sda*, just two partitions (UEFI and LVM Linux).

Now I'm starting to get worried. I hope someone can help me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you really need to *force power-off* ?   Did you try SysRq keys that allow you to speak directly to the linux kernel and cleanly shutdown your machine, even if your GUI/UI has locked up.    Even if you don't remember the keys/commands used, grabbing out a phone or device & searching "magic sysrq" will find the wikipedia article on it which has everything needed to shutdown any GNU/Linux machine safely without needing to *force power off*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried booting from a usd (or CD) and seeing if you can mount the machine's drive?

Comment: Yes. But I can't even find it. Running "fdisk -l", I would expect to find something like /dev/sda? that I can mount. But there is only /dev/sda which is the USB drive. I tried to install Ubuntu just to see if it finds an existing operating system. But it does not.

Comment: Sorry, apparently I did something during the installation that there is no sda*. However, there is a /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root. But when I try to mount that, I get the message "cannot mount; probably corrupted filesystem".

Comment: Was the drive encrypted before? (You're getting beyond my depth soon, I am afraid!)

Comment: That turned out to be quite easy in the end. I just run fsck on /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root and that fixed the problem. I hope that no data got lost in the process though. So you pointed me in the right direction. Now I can sleep well knowing that I should definitely increase my data-backup-frequency.